# Program received signal sigkill but then error disappears

Tags: ios, sigkill

As soon as I launch app in simulator, Xcode switches to main.m and I see this error momentarily most of the time but the weird part is, this is momentarily, error disappears and then app launches.

for me it seems like Xcode gets confused for a while and then it realizes oh there's no error and continues... strange...

I'm more concerned that if there's something I should catch it now but I'm unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you launch an app and still have it launched from before. Sigkill message is from the already running session - it received a sigkill so a new session can be started. Nothing to worry about.

You can see this kill and quit signals if you have debug console turned on.

If you don't want too see this error you should stop the running session (stop button: stop the running scheme or application) prior to running a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Its a kind of bug !! I had faced with this , but here is two solution :

1. Stop the running app then quit iOS simulator . relunch again
2. Restart your Mac

Comment: Us hobbits love having a second lunch ;D